# Service worker.js is not updating changes. Only if cache is cleared

Tags: javascript, laravel, service-worker

This is my first PWA app with laravel. This code is working,it gets registered well, but if I do a change in the code, for example in the HTML, it is not getting update, and the console is not throwing errors, and I dont know why.

I'm using this code to call the service-worker.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
});
```

}

And this is the code of the sw.js

```
var cache_name = 'SW_CACHE';
var urlsToCache = [
'/',
'/register'
];
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(precache());
});
addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
            return response;
        }
        var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();
        return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
            function(response) {
            // Check if we received a valid response
            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                return response;
            }
            var responseToCache = response.clone();
            caches.open(cache_name)
                .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                });
            return response;
            }
        );
        })
    );
});
var fromCache = function (request) {
    return caches.open(cache_name).then(function (cache) {
    cache.match(request).then(function (matching) {
        return matching || Promise.resolve('no-match');
    });
    });
}
var update = function (request) {
    return caches.open(cache_name).then(function (cache) {
    return fetch(request).then(function (response) {
        return cache.put(request, response);
    });
    });
}
var precache = function() {
    return caches.open(cache_name).then(function (cache) {
    return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    });
}
```

Y also used skipWaiting(); method inner Install method, but it crash my app and have to unload the sw from chrome://serviceworker-internals/

Comment: Does it get the update after you Open the App for a little bit, close the app and then open it again? I believe that is how it works. Cache is used when the app is opened while uploading changes in the background for the next time it is opened.

Answer (score 2):

This is what service worker lifecycle suppose to work: a new service worker won't take place, unless:

- The window or tabs controlled by the older service worker are closed and reopened
- 'Update on reload' option is checked in Chrome devtools

Here is an official tutorial explained it well: [The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle)

Answer (score 2):

Service worker will always use the existing worker. Two thinks you can do is in chrome there is an option to set update on load

1. Goto InspectorWindow (f12) -> application -> and check update on reload.
2. if you want immediate update you can choose the network first cache approach. which will take the latest from server always and use the cache only in offline mode. see the link for more information

   [How API is getting cached effectively, Using Service worker in Angular 5 using Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639114/how-api-is-getting-cached-effectively-using-service-worker-in-angular-5-using-a/49660844#49660844)